# Inserting valid json with copy into postgres table

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Valid JSON can naturally have the backslash character: \. When you insert data in a SQL statement like so:

```
sidharth=# create temp table foo(data json);
CREATE TABLE
sidharth=# insert into foo values( '{"foo":"bar", "bam": "{\"mary\": \"had a lamb\"}" }');
INSERT 0 1

sidharth=# select * from foo;

data                         
\-----------------------------------------------------

{"foo":"bar", "bam": "{\"mary\": \"had a lamb\"}" }
(1 row)
```

Things work fine.

But if I copy the JSON to a file and run the copy command I get:

```
sidharth=# \copy foo from './tests/foo' (format text); 


ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "mary" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"foo":"bar", "bam": "{"mary...
COPY foo, line 1, column data: "{"foo":"bar", "bam": "{"mary": "had a lamb"}" }"
```

Seems like postgres is not processing the backslashes. I think because of http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html and
it I am forced to use double backslash. And that works, i.e. when the file contents are:

```
{"foo":"bar", "bam": "{\\"mary\\": \\"had a lamb\\"}" }
```

The copy command works. But is it correct to expect special treatment for json data types 
because afterall above is not a valid json.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334512/postgres-copy-with-command-strips-escapes-from-json-file-also-loads-each-line-a/52355439#52355439. I think this explains how to solve this..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import a JSON file into PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql)

Answer (score 24):

http://adpgtech.blogspot.ru/2014/09/importing-json-data.html

```
copy the_table(jsonfield) 
from '/path/to/jsondata' 
csv quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02';
```

Comment: Please provide more context for a link you post in an answer, and for the code snippet. [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is, at the time of writing, the correct answer to the OP's question: how to read json from the filesystem *without* having to apply special escape syntax (thus rendering the json invalid). Unfortunately most users will pass over the answer due to downvotes and low SO rep. Answer could be better but it was clearly just a drive by from a non-SO user...

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL's default bulk load format, `text`, is a tab separated markup. It requires backslashes to be escaped because they have special meaning for (e.g.) the `\N` null placeholder.

Observe what PostgreSQL generates:

```
regress=> COPY foo TO stdout;
{"foo":"bar", "bam": "{\\"mary\\": \\"had a lamb\\"}" }
```

This isn't a special case for json at all, it's true of any string. Consider, for example, that a string - including json - might contain embedded tabs. Those must be escaped to prevent them from being seen as another field.

You'll need to generate your input data properly escaped. Rather than trying to use the PostgreSQL specific `text` format, it'll generally be easier to use `format csv` and use a tool that writes correct CSV, with the escaping done for you on writing.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. Specifically why the escaping is not done by PostgreSQL? It sounds like PostgreSQL accepts a tab separated file (that could contain JSON within), rather than a purely JSON file.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski That's correct. It's TSV. `COPY` isn't used for loading single fields, it's for loading *tables*.