# Loading json data from a file into Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I need to load data from multiple JSON files each having multiple records within them to a Postgres table. I am using the following code but it does not work (am using pgAdmin III on windows)

```
COPY tbl_staging_eventlog1 ("EId", "Category", "Mac", "Path", "ID")
from 'C:\\SAMPLE.JSON' 
delimiter ','
;
```

Content of SAMPLE.JSON file is like this (giving two records out of many such):

```
[{"EId":"104111","Category":"(0)","Mac":"ABV","Path":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google","ID":"System.Byte[]"},{"EId":"104110","Category":"(0)","Mac":"BVC","Path":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google","ID":"System.Byte[]"}]
```

Comment: Which Postgres version? 9.3? 9.4?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24196160/3961156

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import a JSON file into PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
BEGIN;
-- let's create a temp table to bulk data into
create temporary table temp_json (values text) on commit drop;
copy temp_json from 'C:\SAMPLE.JSON';

-- uncomment the line above to insert records into your table
-- insert into tbl_staging_eventlog1 ("EId", "Category", "Mac", "Path", "ID") 

select values->>'EId' as EId,
       values->>'Category' as Category,
       values->>'Mac' as Mac,
       values->>'Path' as Path,
       values->>'ID' as ID      
from   (
           select json_array_elements(replace(values,'\','\\')::json) as values 
           from   temp_json
       ) a; 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful

Comment: @anil: so you should accept this answer as the correct one.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson : you have to run the entire script in a single transaction. Probably you are running it as a "script" and when it runs the "select" clause, the temp table was already dropped (on commit drop).

Comment: Nice also need to cast for Id like this (CAST(values->>'ID' AS integer)) AS ID

Comment: This solution gives me an error of: 

CREATE TABLE
COPY 1
psql:insertJson.sql:64: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Expected "," or "}", but found "1.0".
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...number": null, "annotations": "<?xml version="1.0...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Andrew Dunstan's PostgreSQL and Technical blog](http://adpgtech.blogspot.com/2014/09/importing-json-data.html?m=1)

> In text mode, COPY will be simply defeated by the presence of a backslash in the JSON. So, for example, any field that contains an embedded double quote mark, or an embedded newline, or anything else that needs escaping according to the JSON spec, will cause failure. And in text mode you have very little control over how it works - you can't, for example, specify a different ESCAPE character. So text mode simply won't work.

so we have to turn around to the `CSV` format mode.

```sql
copy the_table(jsonfield) 
from '/path/to/jsondata' 
csv quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02';
```

In the official document [sql-copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html), some Parameters list here:

```sql
COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
    [ WHERE condition ]

where option can be one of:

    FORMAT format_name
    FREEZE [ boolean ]
    DELIMITER 'delimiter_character'
    NULL 'null_string'
    HEADER [ boolean ]
    QUOTE 'quote_character'
    ESCAPE 'escape_character'
    FORCE_QUOTE { ( column_name [, ...] ) | * }
    FORCE_NOT_NULL ( column_name [, ...] )
    FORCE_NULL ( column_name [, ...] )
    ENCODING 'encoding_name'
```

- FORMAT

  - Selects the data format to be read or written: text, csv (Comma Separated Values), or binary. The default is text.
- QUOTE

  - Specifies the quoting character to be used when a data value is quoted. The default is double-quote. This must be a single one-byte character. This option is allowed only when using CSV format.
- DELIMITER

  - Specifies the character that separates columns within each row (line) of the file. The default is a tab character in text format, a comma in CSV format. This must be a single one-byte character. This option is not allowed when using binary format.
- NULL

  - Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for cases where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings. This option is not allowed when using binary format.
- HEADER

  - Specifies that the file contains a header line with the names of each column in the file. On output, the first line contains the column names from the table, and on input, the first line is ignored. This option is allowed only when using CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql).
Running the following command would generate INSERT statements that you can pipe into psql:

```
$ jq -c .[] *.json | spyql -Otable=tbl_staging_eventlog1 "SELECT json->EId, json->Category, json->Mac, json->Path, json->ID FROM json TO sql"
INSERT INTO "tbl_staging_eventlog1"("EId","Category","Mac","Path","ID") VALUES ('104111','(0)','ABV','C:\Program Files (x86)\Google','System.Byte[]'),('104110','(0)','BVC','C:\Program Files (x86)\Google','System.Byte[]');
```

jq is used to transform the json arrays from all json files in the current directory into json lines (1 json object per line) and then spyql takes care of converting json lines into INSERT statements.

To import the data into PostgreSQL:

```
$ jq -c .[] *.json | spyql -Otable=tbl_staging_eventlog1 "SELECT json->EId, json->Category, json->Mac, json->Path, json->ID FROM json TO sql" | psql  -U your_user_name -h your_host your_database
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of spyql.