# Insert JSON into PostgreSQL that contains quotation marks

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to import a JSON file into a table. I'm using the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33130304/1663462:

```
create temporary table temp_json (values text) on commit drop;
copy temp_json from 'data.json';

select
  values->>'annotations' as annotationstext

from   (
           select json_array_elements(replace(values,'\','\\')::json) as values
           from   temp_json
       ) a;
```

Json file content is:

```
{"annotations": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"}
```

I have verified that this is a valid JSON file.

The json file contains a `\"` which I presume is responsible for the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE
COPY 1
psql:insertJson2.sql:13: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Expected "," or "}", but found "1.0".
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"annotations": "<?xml version="1.0...
```

Are there any additional characters that need to be escaped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `copy` command processes escape ('\') characters for text format without any options there are two ways to import such data.

1) Process file using external utility via `copy ... from program`, for example using `sed`:

```
copy temp_json from program 'sed -e ''s/\\/\\\\/g'' data.json';
```

It will replace all backslashes to doubled backslashes, which will be converted back to single ones by `copy`.

2) Use `csv` import:

```
copy temp_json from 'data.json' with (format csv, quote '|', delimiter E'\t');
```

Here you should to set `quote` and `delimiter` characters such that it does not occur anywhere in your file.

And after that just use direct conversion:

```
select values::json->>'annotations' as annotationstext from temp_json;
```

Comment: I don't think I can use the direct conversion mentioned. It gives an error of ` ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
LINE 2:   values->>'annotations' as annotations
                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: It does work with `from   (select values::json from   temp_json) a;` though.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski See my example: `values::json->>'annotations'` By "direct" I mean "without additional string processing like `replace`".

Comment: If I change the temp table definition to `create temporary table temp_json (values jsonb) on commit drop;` it works directly. Really happy with this elegant solution!