# Postgresql copy fails on pretty printed JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

I have a file with JSON data in it. The file was given to me "pretty printed" (with indents, etc), but the PostgreSQL `\copy` fails to load it. It gives the following error:

```
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {
COPY test_data, line 1, column data: "{"
```

This error is easy to reproduce. Create a temp table:

```
 CREATE TEMP TABLE target(data jsonb);
```

Next create 2 files. In file1, put the following text:

```
{
    "catalog_name":"foo","sale_date":"2016-02-09T00:00:00"
}
```

In file2:

```
{"catalog_name":"foo","sale_date":"2016-02-09T00:00:00"}
```

The `\copy` fails on file1 but succeeds on file2.

According to [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) they are both valid json strings.

Is it possible to use `\copy` to load file2 without any modifications to the file?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.5

Comment: I think you have to keep every record in a single line for the default COPY input format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190039/inserting-valid-json-with-copy-into-postgres-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is not very sensitive to newlines, you could try stripping them from the `JSON` input.

For e.g.

```
cat input.json | tr -d '\n' > input2.json
```

Using the new input file should work.