# how to import file json in posgresql table

Tags: json, postgresql, copy

I search how to import json data in table postgresql with the command copy
this is a picture of my json file.

```
[{"csgn":{},"err":["no error"],"num":"884","name":{},"mail":null},{"csgn"....
```

[image]

> COPY tbl_import_test_json (csgn,**err**, num,
>    name, mail) from '/tmp/FILOUT.json' delimiter ',';

This command doesn't work, i have a problem to extract field **err**.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you made any attempts, read the documentation or at least googled your question?

Comment: I think this can help you:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I import a JSON file into PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql)

Comment: the command into this post doesn't works. this is why i post my question. This post doesn't cleary explan how to extract from a file.

Comment: Can you please add sample json instead of screen shot? What error(s) did you get?

Comment: the error is:  missing data for column err