# How to import json file in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to import json file into a PostgreSQL.
Example data:

```
 {
  "asin":"2094869245",
  "title":"5 LED Bicycle Rear Tail Red Bike Torch Laser Beam Lamp Light",
  "price":8.26,
  "imhUrl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51RtwnJwtBL._SY300_.jpg"
 }

 {
  "asin":"7245456259",
  "title":"Black Mountain Products Single Resistance Band - Door Anchor,
  "price":10.49,
  "imhUrl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/411Ikpf122L._SY300_.jpg"
 }`
```

Would like the result to look like:

```
data
--------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "asin":"2094869245",
  "title":"5 LED Bicycle Rear Tail Red Bike Torch Laser Beam Lamp Light",
  "price":8.26,
  "imhUrl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51RtwnJwtBL._SY300_.jpg"
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "asin":"7245456259",
  "title":"Black Mountain Products Single Resistance Band - Door Anchor,
  "price":10.49,
  "imhUrl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/411Ikpf122L._SY300_.jpg"
}
```

The data is type json.

My JSON FILE will be stored in a single JSON column called data.

Comment: So the file contains invalid JSON and you want to split it up in valid JSON values?

Comment: NO.i have json file valid and i want to import him in a single json column in postgres.

Comment: Your first example is an invalid JSON value. Is that supposed to be two files or just one file? If it's one file, then how are the individual objects separated?

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612658/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382)

Comment: no is just one file and the individual objects are separated with {}.

Comment: Then your example is missing a `,` between the values - as shown, this **is** invalid JSON.

Comment: okaay thank uu for your response. I tested the instructions of the two links but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove the newline in your JSON file like this:

```
{ "asin":"2094869245", "title":"5 LED Bicycle Rear Tail Red Bike Torch Laser Beam Lamp Light","price":8.26,  "imhUrl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51RtwnJwtBL._SY300_.jpg"}
{ "asin":"7245456259",  "title":"Black Mountain Products Single Resistance Band - Door Anchor",  "price":10.49,  "imhUrl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/411Ikpf122L._SY300_.jpg" }
```

you can load to a table with copy command:

```
create table js (a json);

copy js from '/tmp/data.json'  DELIMITER '^'  CSV  QUOTE ''''  ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: very helpful @anthony-sotolongo.  worked perfectly.