# Importing JSON into postgresql invalid input syntax for type json

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to import some data into a PostgreSQL database. The data is stored in a JSON file (`file.json`) that looks like this:

```
[
        {
         "key1": 12,
         "key2": 2
        },
        {
         "key1": 151,
         "key2": 9
        }
]
```

I'm using `psql` and the instructions are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39224859/8201676). The table that JSON data will be imported in is created:

```
create table table_import (doc json);
```

While copying data into the table

```
\copy table_import from '/location/file.json'
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...
COPY table_import, line 1, column doc: "["
```

Since I'm doing exactly what the instructions in the answer are, I'm starting a new thread.

Comment: When importing a text file, each line in the file is one row to be inserted. You need to write the JSON into a single line in the input file.

Comment: You can prepare the file with https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/ as follows: `jq -c '.[]' <file>.json > <new-file>.json` (the `-c` creates a compact format without line breaks). Then you can import the `<new-file>.json`

Answer (score 1):

In the example you're referring to the table is populated directly by *`INSER INTO`* and *`VALUES`* and later treated as array of JSON objects.

When importing with ***`\COPY table FROM file.json`*** each JSON object should be on one line. This would be your `file.json`:

```
{"key1": 12,"key2": 2}
{"key1": 151,"key2": 9}
```

See *[the last post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445995/6618610)* on the page you're referring to or the beginning of *[my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58992119/6618610).*