# Load JSON Data to PostgreSQL 11 Tables

Tags: json, database, postgresql-11

Need to load the following JSON to PostgreSQL-11 tables and need help with it:

`[
{
"id":"1",
"name":"abc_xyz",
"language":"English",
"title":"facebook",
"description":"This is a test",
"categories":[
                "https://facebook/category/28",
                "https://facebook/category/29",
                "https://facebook/category/30",
                "https://facebook/category/31"
              ]
    },
    "id":"2",
    "name":"abc_xyz",
    "language":"French",
    "title":"Twitter",
    "description":"This is another test",
    "categories":[
                    "https://twitter/category/2",
                    "https://twitter/category/23",
                    "https://twitter/category/35"
                  ]
    }
    ]`

The JSON data needs to be loaded into two tables:
TableA Columns:

```
id int, 
name varchar,
language varchar, 
description varchar
```

TableB Columns:

```
Association_Id serial,
TableA.Id int,
Category_Id int,
Last_Update_Time timestamp DEFAULT NOW()
```

TableA will have rows like :

```
id = 1,
name = abc_xyz,
language = English,
title = facebook,
description = This is a test
```

TableB Rows:

```
Association_Id = 1
TableA_Id = 1
Category_Id  = 28

Association_Id = 2
TableA_Id = 1
Category_Id  = 29

Association_Id = 3
TableA_Id = 1
Category_Id  = 30
```

etc etc.

Please help... Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql

Comment: @StephanSchlecht -- Thanks.. I already looked at that example, however I have a second table to be populated as well from the same JSON. There are more than one Categories associated with the same entry in the JSON. I want to know how to populate the association table.

Comment: One possibility that might or might not be considered is to write a small program in Java or C# or any other language you prefer. It is easy to de-serialize JSON and then you can populate the tables accordingly.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht -- I was looking for a direct query from the DB which could do so, but seems like I will have to do so using a Java/python/C++program. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little program. It is written in Java, but would work in a similar way in another language. It is completely self-contained. I tried to make it minimalistic, but it could still be a good starting point.

It does:

- read in the JSON with the GSON library
- Import of the data into the Postgres database via JDBC prepared statements

**Result**

With the `psql` command line program querying TableA and TableB returns:

```
stephan=# select * from TableA;                                                                                                
 id |  title   |  name   | language |     description      
----+----------+---------+----------+----------------------
  1 | facebook | abc_xyz | English  | This is a test
  2 | Twitter  | abc_xyz | French   | This is another test
(2 rows)

stephan=# select * from TableB;
 association_id | tablea_id | category_id |      last_update_time      
----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------
             29 |         1 |          28 | 2019-06-13 18:04:52.671833
             30 |         1 |          29 | 2019-06-13 18:04:52.671833
             31 |         1 |          30 | 2019-06-13 18:04:52.671833
             32 |         1 |          31 | 2019-06-13 18:04:52.671833
             33 |         2 |           2 | 2019-06-13 18:04:52.692635
             34 |         2 |          23 | 2019-06-13 18:04:52.692635
             35 |         2 |          35 | 2019-06-13 18:04:52.692635
(7 rows)
```

**Java**

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.sql.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class Entry {
    int id;
    String name;
    String language;
    String title;
    String description;
    String[] categories;
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"abc_xyz\",\"language\":\"English\",\"title\":\"facebook\",\"description\":\"This is a test\",\"categories\":[\"https://facebook/category/28\",\"https://facebook/category/29\",\"https://facebook/category/30\",\"https://facebook/category/31\"]},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"abc_xyz\",\"language\":\"French\",\"title\":\"Twitter\",\"description\":\"This is another test\",\"categories\":[\"https://twitter/category/2\",\"https://twitter/category/23\",\"https://twitter/category/35\"]}]";
        try {
            Entry[] entries = readJSON(json);
            importIntoDB(entries);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Entry[] readJSON(String json) {
        Entry[] entries;
        Gson g = new Gson();
        entries = g.fromJson(json, Entry[].class);
        return entries;
    }

    private static Connection createConnection()
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/stephan";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "stephan");
        props.setProperty("password", "secret");
        //props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
    }

    private static void importIntoDB(Entry[] entries)
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection connection = createConnection();
        try (connection) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement insertTableA = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO TableA (id, name, language, title, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            PreparedStatement insertTableB = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO TableB (TableA_Id, Category_Id) VALUES (?, ?)");
            for (Entry entry : entries) {
                insertTableA.setInt(1, entry.id);
                insertTableA.setString(2, entry.name);
                insertTableA.setString(3, entry.language);
                insertTableA.setString(4, entry.title);
                insertTableA.setString(5, entry.description);

                insertTableA.execute();

                for (String category : entry.categories) {
                    insertTableB.setInt(1, entry.id);
                    String categoryIdString = category.substring(category.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    int categoryId = Integer.parseInt(categoryIdString);
                    insertTableB.setInt(2, categoryId);
                    insertTableB.execute();
                }
                connection.commit();
            }
            insertTableA.close();
            insertTableB.close();
        }
    }

}
```

**Required Libraries**

The above program requires the Postgres JDBC library and the GSON library for JSON deserialization.

You can download it from here:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar

**Batches**

If you have to import a large amount of entries, you could think about combining the PreparedStatements into batches and then executing many statements at once, take a look at the methods addBatch and executeBatch.