# Fill a Table with data from a json File

Tags: postgresql

Using the following SQL Code

```
copy (select row_to_json(t) from (select * from mytable) t) to '/home/soti/myfile.json';
```

I can export an arbitrary table to a JSON File. Each record is serialized in a single line. That means if the table has 5000 rows, the file will have 5000 rows, too.

Now I want to do the reverse: I want to import an json-file into the table. I.e. if the file contains 5000 lines, each line containing a single json-document, 5000 rows should be inserted into the table.

Is there an easy posibility?

Comment: there is a similar queston here on so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best solution, but **you can import the data through a temp table with a json column**.
I created an example with a settings table which looks like this:

```
create table settings(id int8, key VARCHAR(50), value text);
```

First create a temp table with a single json column

```
create temporary table tmp(data json);
```

Then import the data with copy

```
copy tmp(data) from '/tmp/myfile.json';
```

Now you can load your data with an insert into select from statement

```
insert into settings(id, key, value)
select (data->>'id')::int8, data->>'key', data->>'value' from tmp;
```

Or if you don't want to specify the columns manaully you can use **json_populate_recordset** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql)

```
insert into settings
select p.* 
from 
 json_populate_recordset(null::settings, (select json_agg(data) from tmp)) as p
```

And finally drop the temp table

```
drop table tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For your solution, the sql needs to specify the columns-names. I was hoping to find a solution using json_populate_record() like this one (which only inserts a single row):

    insert into mytable select * from json_populate_record(null::mytable, '{"id":5,"key":"TEST","value":"jfdklas"}');

Comment: Oh, I didn't get that part.

Comment: Check this question aswell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql, it might help to find the answer, the json_populate_recordset function might be what are you looking for.

Comment: I found a way to do this with the json_populate_recordset function, check my updated answer