# How can I convert my json object into postgres table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to insert bulk data into postgres. So I have converted my data into json object and now I want to insert that data into a physical table the json object can contain over 100k records. So I want to do it dynamically by using postgres function. My question is how can I query my sample data as a table

This is the sample json data

```
[
  {
    "sequence": 123123.0,
    "Card number ": "12312qwe",
    "Tracking number": 1231233.0,
    "Expiry Date": 43741.0
  },
  {
    "sequence": 123123.0,
    "Card number ": "12312qwe",
    "Tracking number": 1231233.0,
    "Expiry Date": 43741.0
  },
 {
    "sequence": 123123.0,
    "Card number ": "12312qwe",
    "Tracking number": 1231233.0,
    "Expiry Date": 43741.0
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you try this one,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create a table (e.g.`tab`) with `json` column (e.g.`jsondata`) and by using [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) function :

```
create table tab as
with tab as
(
 select '[
  {
    "sequence": 123123.0,
    "Card number ": "12312qwe",
    "Tracking number": 1231233.0,
    "Expiry Date": 43741.0
  },
  {
    "sequence": 123123.0,
    "Card number ": "12312qwe",
    "Tracking number": 1231233.0,
    "Expiry Date": 43741.0
  },
 {
    "sequence": 123123.0,
    "Card number ": "12312qwe",
    "Tracking number": 1231233.0,
    "Expiry Date": 43741.0
  }
]'::json as jsondata
)
select js ->> 'sequence' as sequence, js ->> 'Card number ' as Cardnumber, 
       js ->> 'Tracking number' as Trackingnumber, js ->> 'Expiry Date' as ExpiryDate
  from
  (
    select json_array_elements(jsondata) as js
      from tab
  ) q1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=155ef29eded1c37e2c8c583477c50582)</kbd>