# ERROR: extra data after last expected column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a json file as:

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ cat test_cgs.json
{"technology":"AAA","vendor":"XXX","name":"RBNI","temporal_unit":"hour","regional_unit":"cell","dataset_metadata":"{\"name\": \"RBNI\", \"intervals_epoch_seconds\": [[1609941600, 1609945200]], \"identifier_column_names\": [\"CELLID\", \"CELLNAME\", \"NETWORK\"], \"vendor\": \"XXX\", \"timestamp_column_name\": \"COLLECTTIME\", \"regional_unit\": \"cell\"}","rk":1}
```

which I am trying to upload to below table in `Postgres`

```
 CREATE TABLE temp_test_table
( 
  technology       character varying(255),
  vendor           character varying(255),
  name             character varying(255),
  temporal_unit    character varying(255),
  regional_unit    character varying(255),
  dataset_metadata json,
  rk    character varying(255)
);
```

and here is my copy command

```
db-state=> \copy temp_test_table(technology,vendor,name,temporal_unit,regional_unit,dataset_metadata,rk) FROM '/home/eksinvi/test_cgs.json' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',' quote E'\b' ESCAPE '\';
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY temp_test_table, line 1: "{"technology":"AAA","vendor":"XXX","name":"RBNI","temporal_unit":"hour","regional_unit":"cell","data..."
```

I even tried loading this file to big query table but no luck

```
bq load --autodetect --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --allow_quoted_newlines --allow_jagged_rows --ignore_unknown_values test-project:vikrant_test_dataset.cg_test_table "gs://test-bucket-01/test/test_cgs.json"
```

any of the solution would work for me. I want to load this json either to `Postgres` table or `bigquery` table.

Comment: You're table has 7 fields. Your json file has only one field, the json-payload. That's not going to work in combination with COPY.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems. In my case, it was related to NULL columns and encoding of the file. I also had to specify a custom delimiter because my columns sometimes included the default limiter and it would make the copy fail.

```
\\copy mytable FROM 'filePath.dat' (DELIMITER E'\\t', FORMAT CSV, NULL '', ENCODING 'UTF8'  );
```

In my case, I was exporting data to a CSV file from SQL Server and importing it to postgres. In SQL Server, we had unicode characters that would show up as "blanks" but that would screw up the copy command. I had to search the SQL table for those characters with regex queries and eliminate invalid characters. It's an edge case but that was part of the problem in my case.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using below since delimiter seems to be ',' in my case.. \copy temp_test_table(technology,vendor,name,temporal_unit,regional_unit,dataset_metadata,rk) FROM '/home/xyz/test_cgs.json' (DELIMITER ',', FORMAT CSV, NULL '', ENCODING 'UTF8');

Comment: getting this error message ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "dataset_metadata" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: dataset_metadata...