# PostgreSQL Import JSON that structured array -> array?

Tags: postgresql

As I googled and some read SO posts like [sql - How can I import a JSON file into PostgreSQL? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql), I found a way to parse/import JSON that structured array -> object, such as following(a), using `json_populate_recordset`, or line by line object, like (b), but I want to import JSON that structured array -> array, like following(c).

(a)

```
'[
      {
        "id": 23635,
        "name": "Jerry Green",
        "comment": "Imported from facebook."
      },
      {
        "id": 23636,
        "name": "John Wayne",
        "comment": "Imported from facebook."
      }
]
```

(b)

```
{"id": 23635,"name": "Jerry Green","comment": "Imported from facebook."}
{"id": 23636,"name": "John Wayne","comment": "Imported from facebook."}
```

(c) ←← wanna parse (actually hundreds of lines not just two)

```
[
    [
        1621900800000,
        38642.4422973396
    ],
    [
        1621932800000,
        38192.49969227624
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea how you could do this.

```sql
insert into my_table (my_bigint_column, my_numeric_column)
select (ja ->> 0)::bigint,  (ja ->> 1)::numeric -- mapping expressions here
from jsonb_array_elements
(
$JSONTEXT$
[
    [
        1621900800000,
        38642.4422973396
    ],
    [
        1621932800000,
        38192.49969227624
    ]
]
$JSONTEXT$::jsonb) ja;
```

or, as a parameterized query

```sql
insert into my_table (my_bigint_column, my_numeric_column)
select (ja ->> 0)::bigint,  (ja ->> 1)::numeric  -- mapping expressions here
from jsonb_array_elements (:jsontext::jsonb) ja;
```

Hundreds of lines would not be an issue.