# Geojson polygon data in CSV file, how to import into postgreSQL

Tags: csv, geojson, postgresql-9.3

I have csv files with polygon data in geojson form where each line in the csv is similar to that shown below:

{"type": "Feature", "properties": {},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-80.86249607459162, 26.200956843221704], [-80.86270930028365, 26.200960980745556], [-80.86271370674712, 26.200778163395427], [-80.86250049530878, 26.200774026141644], [-80.86249607459162, 26.200956843221704]]]}}

I need to add these to a postgreSQL database (and ultimately a gdb) but I have no idea how.  Please, any help? Sorry, new to postgreSQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import a JSON file into PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql)

Comment: If you have a text file where every line is a single JSON object,  then that's a text file full of JSON objects, not a .csv file.

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I also found this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/storing-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgresql-with-postgis   which is more specific to geojson, but it keeps telling me it's expecting a , or ] Instead of { in the very first line. Maybe because it's over 7 years old? :(

Comment: My only interaction with any PostgreSQL database is to forlornly dispatch SELECT statements at one though the back end of SAP BusinessObjects so I don't know what built-in text/JSON-parsing tools it offers. Are you able to process this file e.g. with Python before passing it to PostgreSQL? It might be easier if you could split the file into separate JSON objects upstream and give them to PostgreSQL one at a time.

Comment: I am much better with Python, I think I'll give that a try :)