# Postgres COPY with command strips escapes from JSON file (Also loads each line as seperate row)

Tags: json, postgresql, copy

If I have the following json file

```
C:\PostgresStage>type test2.json
{"key":"Hello \"World\""}
```

And I try to load it into a json or text column using the COPY command I end up with invalid JSON because copy appears to strip the escape characters from the file as can be seen below

```
postgres=# \d+ T1
                               Table "public.t1"
Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 data   | text |           |          |         | extended |              |


postgres=# delete from T1;
DELETE 1
postgres=# copy t1 from 'c:\PostgresStage\test2.json';
COPY 1
postgres=# select  * from T1;
          data
-------------------------
 {"key":"Hello "World""}
 (1 row)


postgres=# select data::jsonb from T1;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "World" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"key":"Hello "World...
postgres=#
```

Is there anyway to prevent this..

Also if I have 'pretty' JSON such as this

```
C:\PostgresStage>type test2.json
{
  "key":"Hello \"World\""
}
```

It gets loaded as 3 rows. Is there anyway to use copy to load the entire file as one row.

Finally is there anyway to use COPY to pass a parameter to a function rather than load a row into a table

Comment: JSON is a binary format, copy is not designed fro binary data. Maybe there's a better way, why do you want to read such a file directly into the database?

Comment: @jasen Sorry to disagree. JSON is a text format. I think you may be getting confused with the 'jsonb' datatype which is Postgres's internal binary representation of JSON. I want to load a large JSON file into the database in order to decompose it using Postgres's JSON operators.

Comment: I suppose it's less a binary format than CSV and copy can handle that., can you format your JSON as CSV?

Comment: Not really, JSON is a dump of an entire Oracle Database schema...

Answer (score 16):

For JSON documents that are not "pretty printed", eg the entire document is a single line in the file, a hack is to use

```
 copy t1 from 'c:\PostgresStage\test2.json' csv quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02';
```

Thanks to http://adpgtech.blogspot.com/2014/09/importing-json-data.html

Comment: This solution will work for me since I am using NODE pipes to pass the JSON so I can pass the JSON through a transform that will strip end of lines from the document...

Comment: On, Windows, if the file is too large the following is needed: `\copy t1 from program 'pwsh -Command "gc D:\t1.json"' csv quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02'`. This assumes that you have Powershell (pwsh).

Comment: Here is another workaround to `could not stat file` error that might appear when you try to use `\copy` to import large files (>2GB). This one uses built-in `cmd` and is equivalent to the one posted by @ivan `\copy t1 from program 'cmd /c "type D:\t1.json"' csv quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02';`

Comment: I cannot believe that works lol, thank you!

Comment: Unbelievable find. It works.